# Can't utilize an existing Class in a new C# project?

Tags: c#

I'm a student learning mainly C++, but this term we have to code our math assignments using C#.

Our professor supplied a basic skeleton program but I'm not very good at C#. He gave us two class files (.cs) but when I add them to my project, I'm unable to utilize them at all. I can't create a class object from either class.

The classes are just Line3d and Point3d. They have the variables needed to compute points and collision.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: you need to check two things, if the class are public, and two, you must include the namespace in your main file

Comment: Classes should not be public if you add them to your project. Use 'Ctrl+.' to resolve namespace for these classes or write using manually.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Answer (score 2):

Compile your project.

Use `Ctrl` + `.` or bulb icon (type your class name you want to use and locate your cursor position over that class name) to resolve namespace for these classes or write [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) manually.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

C# classes are normally encapsulated in namespaces. In Visual Studio, adding a new class will generate a file containing a namespace similar to `PROJECT_NAME.SUBFOLDER.SUBSUBFOLDER` For example:

```
// MyClass.cs
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

And then you can reference that from another class in the same namespace, but you can't reference it from a class in another namespace (unless it's a namespace that starts with `MyProject.`).

```
// Line3d.cs
using System;

namespace TemplateProject
{
    public class Line3d 
    {

    }
}

// MyClass.cs
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public Line3d LineInstance {get;set;}
    }
}
```

In this example, it won't work because the compiler doesn't know which namespace Line3d exists in (and, indeed, two class with the exact same name could exist in two different namespaces). You need to instruct the compiler to include classes from the `TemplateProject` namespace (note this doesn't include classes in the `TemplateProject.ChildNamespace` namespace):

```
// MyClass.cs
using System;
using TemplateProject;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public Line3d LineInstance {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to find the `Line3d` class and use it.

Besides manually referencing the namespace, you can also right-click an unknown class reference, select "Quick actions and Refactorings...", and then you will see something like "using TemplateProject;". Click on this and it will automatically add the `using` for you.

You can also use the `Ctrl`+`.` keyboard shortcut, which does the same as right-click/Quick actions, if you don't want to use the mouse.

Answer (score -2):

select your project and press [ Shift + Alt + A ] to add existing files.

you can see dialog form that allows to open cs file on project.

After that, you can use professor's class files.